# ContentValue not accepting BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi guys i am trying to do this

```
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

  initialValues.put("monthlyBudget",account.monthlyBudge
```

where `MonthlyBudget is BigDecimal` variable.

Now it gives an error that change the type of `monthlyBudget to String`.

How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: How can this be about objective-c *and* Java? What is the type of `initialValues`? Is that your `ContentValues`? The JavaDoc for `ContentValues` certainly doesn't *show* an overload for `BigDecimal`, so why had you expected this to work?

Comment: well i have edited the post. And well i want to save Bigdecimal value, actually currency in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ContentValues`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) documentation lists all the overloads of `put` - and none of them takes a `BigDecimal`, so I'm not surprised it's failing.

Two options you could take:

- If this is a currency value (which it sounds like) you may be able to deal with it to a fixed precision, e.g. 2 decimal places, and with relatively limited range. Just multiply your `BigDecimal` by 100, take the integer result as a `long` and then put the `long` into your `ContentValues`. When you extract it later, create a `BigDecimal` from the `long` and divide it by 100. (Or change all your code to treat the budget as an integer number of cents everywhere, potentially.)
- You could store the string representation, and pass that string to the `BigDecimal` constructor when you fetch it.

Comment: thanks for that, i'll try this. Also i got a variable with Date class. what should i do with it?

Comment: @umar: It's easy to convert between `Date` and `long`, as that's basically all there is to it - use `getTime` to get the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, and pass it back into the `Date` constructor to get the original `Date` back.